# SQL Server Reporting Services not passing the correct parameter from SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a SQL stored procedure that calls the most recent date from a certain cycle. This date includes a bunch of data points that are populated into the report. When I execute the SELECT statement alone, it pulls the correct date I want. In SSRS, it pulls the second to last date... I have the TOP 1 in there to select the most recent along with the DESC. I was wondering if I have an issue with my parameters within SSRS. The report is set up as 2 sub-reports. The first sub-report is just an overview page and the second is the actual report that contains all the data with the Start and End date. @Phase1Start and @Phase1End are my parameters being pass to the sub-report that contains all the data points. Also, the reason I do not have single quotes around the 1 is because CycleComplete is a bit. Any solutions?

I have already tried:

-Changing the date types from datetime's to text's
-Including single quotes around the 1

Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
DECLARE @Phase1Start as datetime
DECLARE @Phase1End as datetime

  SELECT
        @Phase1Start = (SELECT TOP 1 [CycleStartedOn] FROM [dbo].[IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] WHERE [CycleComplete] = 1 ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC) 
        ,@Phase1End = (SELECT TOP 1 [CycleEndedOn] FROM [dbo].[IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] WHERE [CycleComplete] = 1 ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC) 

  DECLARE @tblReports TABLE
(    
    Phase1Start datetime
    ,Phase1End datetime
    )

    INSERT INTO @tblReports
(    
    Phase1Start 
    ,Phase1End 
    )

Values
(   
    @Phase1Start
    ,@Phase1End
    )

SELECT * FROM @tblReports

END
```

The stored procedure compiles correctly and gives me the start and end times I want. The issue is within SSRS not pulling the correct date from the stored procedure even though I have @Phase1Start and Phase1End as my parameters being passed to the sub-report that contains all the data.

Comment: Are you running in development locally?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. SSRS and the SQL database both reside on the same server I am working on yes. And essentially no, I am working on a virtual machine.

Comment: Can you hit the refresh arrow on the report toolbar in VS or refresh the dataset to make sure you are not hitting a cache issue. While in dev mode, the data is cached in the *.data files.

Comment: That did not seem to change anything. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: your parameter can be set using a query.. create a dataset that is `SELECT Top(1) Phase1Start = [CycleStartedOn], Phase1End = [CycleEndedOn] FROM [dbo].[IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] WHERE [CycleComplete] = 1 ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC`  and under Default Values for the parameter, pick get values from a query, select the new dataset and pick the correct column for each param

Comment: Is the data source in SSRS pointing to the same database? I know, but I had to ask. Also, any reason why you aren't using `Max()` function instead of the `Top 1` and `Order by Desc`? And you do realize in the second Select statement, you have `ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC)` even though you are trying to get the latest `CycleEndedOn` date.

Comment: Yes it is pointing to the same database. I am not sure Max and Top 1 would make a difference? I can try and see what happens, thanks. Yes, I am aware that I have CycleStarted on when I am trying to get the end time. But I can double check and see if that helps. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that our first sub query and the second sub query return different records?  Perhaps this might help:

```
SELECT Top(1) @Phase1Start = [CycleStartedOn], @Phase1End = [CycleEndedOn] FROM [dbo].[IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] WHERE [CycleComplete] = 1 ORDER BY [CycleStartedOn] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback, sadly that gives the same output as what I originally had.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the group by

```
SELECT  @Phase1Start = MAX([CycleStartedOn] ) ,
        @Phase1End = MAX([CycleEndedOn])
FROM        [dbo].[IPEC_P_CIP_TKB_PREFLT] 
WHERE    [CycleComplete] = 1
```

Comment: This did not compile. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: Missed the comma when formatting, edit is now available for you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That compiled nicely but did not solve my issue.. Hmmmm...